# Failing to put release

Tags: concourse

I'm getting the following error when trying to put a release in a private repo.
creating release ReleaseName error running command: POST https://api.github.com/repos/my-org/my-repo/releases: 404 Not Found []

prior to getting this error, I was getting:
error running command: GET https://api.github.com/repos/my-org/my-repo.git/releases: 404 Not Found []
so I know the get is now working, and it's something specific to the POST.

My resource config is as follows (admittedly doctored to protect the innocent)

```
- name: gh-release
  type: github-release
  source:
    owner: my-org
    repository: my-repo
    access_token: {{access-token}}
```

and the put looks like this (again doctored):

```
- put: gh-release
  params:
    name: package/name
    tag: version/version
    tag_prefix: package/tag-prefix
    commitish: package/commitish
    globs:
      - package/*.tar.gz
```

I know the access token works for the GET, and I've used it with curl successfully.

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

UPDATE: fixed indentation.

Comment: Is the indentation in your second code sample the way it is in your pipeline?

Comment: not quite, the `put` is indented further, but I hadn't spotted the `globs` - been looking at it too long..  That might be the problem, so I'll see if that fixes it.  Thanks.

Comment: No, that's not it.  I'll update the snippet in the OP :-(.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out that it was a permissions problem.  The user that the token was for only had read access to the repository.  Using a different user token, or updating the repo access to write fixed the issue.